# what kind of pattern should I use to solve this problem

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture

I am working on an requirement(Spring mvc architecture, java 8), actually it's kind of fix ,where I have to filter the data on basis on an condition.
I can filter data in DAO layer that is by applying joins in data base query . But the problem is there are lots of method where I am supposed to apply this condition for filtering data.

First I thought :
I should define an instance variable in DAO class and set this variable via method from Action class(this condition data supposed to come from Action to DAO layer). But it seems very odd and general practice doesn't allow it too.

Other I can search all the method and change the parameter which is also not good practice.
I am not sure how to achieve this.

Does anyone have any idea about this?
any pattern or any suitable method.
E.g.

```
 ActionClass{
    doSOmething(){
    variable condition = object.getCondotion();
    variable someData  = serviceClass.fetchDataOnCondtion(condition);
    }
    } 
    
    ServiceClass{
    fetchDataAOnCondtion(variable condition){
    dataObjectDAO.fetchDataAOnCondtion(condition);
    }
    fetchDataBOnCondtion(variable condition){
    dataObjectDAO.fetchDataBOnCondtion(condition);
    }
    }
    
    someDataObjectDAO{
    fetchDataAOnCondtion(condition){};
    fetchDataBOnCondtion(condition){};
    fetchDataCOnCondtion(condition){};
    fetchDataDOnCondtion(condition){};

    }
```

here in DAO class I am using same condition variable in every method on DAO class , but there are a lot method which is quite tedious to change and also I need to change the interface method def too.

please provide  some suggestion how can I solve this problem?
thanks in advance !

Comment: Do not call your DAO from your Action, provide a Service instead where you implement the Strategy pattern to decide which of a family of possible filtering options you apply. Or just forget about patterns and just have a number of methods in your Service that operate on the result returned by your DAO to do the filtering, and call the appropriate Service method from your Action.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.